# MySql to provide repeat count based on multiple criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table *call* which has two columns **Customer_Phone_Number** & **DateTime**.

What I am trying to do here is, *Repeat count within last 14 days for customers who called me yesterday between 18:00-10:00PM*

Sample file - [Sample_Excel_File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i2r9v7midzioy8b/Sample.xlsx?dl=0)

Please help

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results

Comment: @GordonLinoff Please check now

Answer (score 0):

```
Select customer_telephone_number, count(Calls.DateTime) As Count_Calls
From Calls
Where customer_telephone_number In 
(
  Select customer_telephone_number
  From Calls
  Where time_to_sec(date_time) 
        Between time_to_sec(CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) + time_to_sec('10:00:00')
            And time_to_sec(CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) + time_to_sec('18:00:00')
) CustPhonedYesterday
And time_to_sec(date_time) 
          Between time_to_sec(CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 14 DAY) + time_to_sec('00:00:00')
              And time_to_sec(CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) + time_to_sec('18:00:00')
Group By Calls.customer_telephone_number;
```

Comment: @IshuBhardwaj is there any feedback, please?